# Export To excel with formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, gridview

I was trying to export a table from database to Excel using Gridview in MVC 4. Can anybody tell me how to give colors to the exported rows in excel sheet?

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
{
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = db.StudentRecords.ToList();
        gv.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gv.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
        return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Comment: Consider this excellent component instead: http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two primary ways to go about solving this. The first is to render the data into an existing Excel file (a template file created that has all the formatting embedded in it already). The second is to programmatically format the cells as you render the output.

Generating Excel files (as opposed to simpler CSV files) is non-trivial, so the easiest approach is to use a third party component. I have had much success with Aspose.Cells (in addition to supporting .NET, there are Java versions, and perhaps others). Of course this is not the only component out there. It is a commercial product, but their support is excellent in my experience.

If you do decide to use a component for generating the Excel file, GridView is largely unnecessary, as you can bind or map your dataset into the components object model (in Aspose's case you would be binding your data to a Worksheet).

Here is the Hello World example from Aspose's website. Check out the helloworld.aspx.cs code to see how it works.

http://www.aspose.com/demos/.net-components/aspose.cells/csharp/quick-start/data/hello-world.aspx

Obviously this is a bit more involved than your example, but as far as I understand this is the easiest way to generate complex Excel files (with formatting, formulas, etc). An investment in figuring this out comes in quite handy if you do this sort of thing on a regular basis.

Also, a note about streaming. Aspose allows you to easily stream your file to the HttpResponse stream. For example (from the above documentation):

```
workbook.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response, "HelloWorld.xls", ContentDisposition.Attachment, new XlsSaveOptions(SaveFormat.Excel97To2003));
```

As Mikael noted above, there are other components out there, which make this sort of work much easier and allow for some quite advanced rendering of Excel files.